# How to split a webpage and have clickable links on one side and what those links will display on the other side

Tags: html, css

I want one side of my webpage to have an unordered list of links and when you click on those links information will appear on the other side of the webpage based on which link was clicked. Can this be done with just HTML and CSS if not can I do it in PHP?

This is my current code

```css
article {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 650px;
}

li {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="#Tiger">Tiger</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Hammerhead">Hammerhead</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Bull">Bull</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Great White">Great White</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Mako">Mako</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Greenland">Greenland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Whale">Whale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Thresher">Thresher</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Oceanic">Oceanic WhiteTip</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Goblin">Goblin</a></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using JavaScript by creating an element on the other side of your links then use

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML
```

to edit it's content based on whats clicked (by linking onclick functions to your links).

Editing a webpage after showing it can not be done with only CSS and HTML.

Here is a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBjzWZ)

Comment: Can you give me an example of creating an element on the other side of a link? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML and CSS only** (if you really insist, but it is **kinda nasty, tho**):
Place `<div>`s containing the relevant information to be shown inside the `<li>` elements. When the links are mouseovered (and get `:hover` in terms of CSS), so do the `<div>`s and `<li>`s. Make the `<div>`s hidden (using CSS) and display them only when hovered.

```
li div {display:none;}
li:hover div {display:block; ... }
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Marko36/pen/JBjzZe) demo i made you.

**Client-side javascript / jQuery**..
.. is a much more practical option, where clicking links will change the CSS of respective `<div>`, which can be placed and styled as you wish. Or, using `data-` attribute containing text, this text can be inserted into that single information `<div>` on the right.

Comment: He specifically said that he wants them to show up when clicked on links.
Also, consider better formatting of your posts.

Comment: He specifically said that he wants " just HTML and CSS", so I offered two options, including one that actually respects what ParPro asked for (although not is not perfect and does :hover instead of clicks). 
I have separated these two by bold beginnings, for clarity. I think that is better formatting, than having a separate paragraph for each sentence, or splitting sentences by blocks of code.